# C++ casting to base and "overwriting" vptr issue

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I was just reading a new C++ challenge:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/02/04/challenge-vulnerable-code.aspx

The supplied code if full of issues, some obvious to anybody with good programming habits, some visible only to C++ natives :-)

It is described in the comments, that one particular line (37) is particularly dangerous:

```
ImageFactory::DebugPrintDimensions((ImageFactory::CustomImage*)image);
```

the function then calls a virtual method of `CustomImage` (defined first time in `CustomImage`).

This allegedly causes the first member of `CustomImage` to be treated as the vptr of the instance (it's an `unique_ptr` actually) and make the binary pointed by it treated as executable (perhaps malicious) code..

While I can understand this, I wonder why does this really work.

`CustomImage` is a virtual class, so (probably) its first 4 bytes (just assume X86) are THE vptr, and the `unique_ptr` member is next.. And since the cast doesn't seem to be shifting anything...

... how would it be possible to execute data held by `unique_ptr`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914940/is-it-undefined-behavior-to-cast-from-base-class-to-derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take (and I'm more than happy to be corrected):

Here, `CustomImage` is a polymorphic class (with a vptr as the first "member" under the Windows ABI), but `Image`is not. The order of the definitions means that the `ImageFactory` functions know that `CustomImage` *is an* `Image`, but `main()` does not.

So when the factory does:

```
Image* ImageFactory::LoadFromDisk(const char* imageName)
{
    return new (std::nothrow) CustomImage(imageName);
}
```

the `CustomImage*` pointer is converted to an `Image*` and everything is fine. Because `Image` is not polymorphic, the pointer is adjusted to point to the (POD) `Image` instance inside the `CustomImage` -- but crutially, this is *after* the vptr, because that always comes first in a polymorphic class in the MS ABI (I assume).

However, when we get to

```
ImageFactory::DebugPrintDimensions((ImageFactory::CustomImage*)image);
```

the compiler sees a C-style cast from one class it knows nothing about to another. All it does is take the address it has and pretend it's a `CustomImage*` instead. This address in fact points to the `Image` within the custom image; but because `Image` is empty, and presumably the empty base class optimisation is in effect, it ends up pointing to the first member within `CustomImage`, i.e. the `unique_ptr`.

Now, `ImageFactory::DebugPrintDimensions()` assumes it's been handed a pointer to a fully-complete `CustomImage`, so that the address is equal to the address of the `vptr`. But it hasn't -- it's been handed the address of the `unique_ptr`, because at the point at which is was called, the compiler didn't know any better. So now it dereferences what it thinks is the vptr (really data we're in control of), looks for the offset of the virtual function and blindly exectutes that -- and now we're in trouble.

There are a couple of things that could have helped mitigate this. Firstly, since we're manipulating a derived class via a base class pointer, `Image` should have a virtual destructor. This would have made `Image` polymorphic, and in all probability we wouldn't have had a problem (and we wouldn't leak memory, either).

Secondly, because we're casting from base-to-derived, `dynamic_cast` should have been used rather than the C style cast, which would have involved a run-time check and correct pointer adjustment.

Lastly, if the compiler had all the information to hand when compiling `main()`, it might have been able to warn us (or performed the cast correctly, adjusting for the polymorphic nature of `CustomImage`). So moving the class definitions above `main()` is recommended too.

Comment: Ok, this is an implementation details, but: executing binary held by `unique_ptr` will work here **only** if the `unique_ptr`  **is** the pointer to the binary.. is it so? I mean - is this the way an `unique_ptr` is implemented - it's first N bytes is the pointer to the resource held?

Comment: I've no idea about the MS implementation, but there's no need for a `unique_ptr<T>` to have any data members other than a `T*`, or for it to be polymorphic, so I think it's very likely that the address of the `unique_ptr` is the same as the data inside it.

Comment: And in fact it is, a `pointer` member of type `T*` is the first member of (at least some) `unique_ptr` implementations

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, the memory layout is such that the vptr comes before the base sub-object, like this:

```
class CustomImage {
    void * __vptr;
    Image  __base;  // empty
    unique_ptr<whatever> evil;
};
```

This means that a valid conversion from `Image*` to `CustomImage*` requires subtracting a few bytes from the pointer. However, the evil cast you've posted comes before the class definitions, so it doesn't know how to correctly adjust the pointer. Instead, it acts like `reinterpret_cast`, simply pretending that the pointer points to `CustomImage` without adjusting its value.

Now, since the base class is empty, the pointer inside `unique_ptr` will be misinterpreted as the vptr. This points to another pointer, which will be misinterpreted as the vtable's pointer to the first virtual member function. This in turn points to data loaded from the file, which will be executed as code when that virtual function is called. As the icing on the cake, the memory protection flags are loaded from the file, and not adjusted to prevent execution.

Some lessons here are:

- Avoid C-style casts, especially on pointer or reference types. They fall back to `reinterpret_cast`, leading to a minefield of undefined behaviour, if the conversion isn't valid. (To compound the evil, their syntax is also ungreppable, and easy to miss if you don't read the code too carefully.)
- Avoid non-polymorphic base classes. As well as being conceptually dubious, and making deletion more awkward and error-prone, it can do surprising things to the memory layout as we see here. If the base class were polymorphic, we could use `dynamic_cast` (or avoid the cast altogether by providing suitable virtual functions), with no possibility of an invalid conversion.
- Avoid unnecessary levels of indirection - there's no particular need for `m_imageData` to be a pointer.
- Never put user data in executable memory.

Comment: you obviously don't take Empty Base Opt. into consideration?

Comment: @Parobay: Yes I do. If the base object weren't optimised out, then the conversion would give a pointer pointing to that, rather than the `unique_ptr`, giving (probably) a crash rather than an exploit.

Comment: Your answer is very good, but I can only accept one.. Sorry, it was a fair coin toss..